# Response.WriteFile to parent folder

Tags: asp.net

I have built a website where all of my main menus read from the same .txt file.  many of these pages are in subfolder and have to read the test.txt file from the parent folder

My webiste
test.txt
    Subfoler
       file reading test.txt

I was using  to accomplish this but the files in the subfolder were not updating any changes I made to the test.txt

It was suggested I use <% Response.WriteFile( "test.txt" ) %>.  How do I read the test.txt from a parent directory?  I can not seem to get out of the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Server.MapPath.  It lets you turn virtual URL's into physical paths.  You could try Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("../test.txt"))